# How to pass unity window to ios from unity

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

I've created a unity window like below:

```
private Rect windowRect = new Rect (5, 20, 600, 400);
void OnGUI () 
{
    windowRect = GUI.Window (0, windowRect, WindowFunction, "My Window");
}
```

Now I need to add a `UIView` from iOS to this given window to show an image from iOS.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an alternative : we can take frame from unity and with that frame can create uiview in xcode.